# How do I list items from 3 separated listboxes if their item numbers are different?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

**Hello!**

Task: 3 people got murdered while staying at 3 different hotels. The murders did not happen on the same day. You have 3 lists from each hotel, with the names of people staying there. If you find matching names list them as suspects.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) //I have 3 different 'n's, n2 is the largest, that is why I use it here (n - listBox1; n2 - listBox2; n3 - listBox3)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(listBox1.Text[i]) == Convert.ToString(listBox2.Text[i]) || Convert.ToString(listBox1.Text[i]) == Convert.ToString(listBox3.Text[i]) || Convert.ToString(listBox2.Text[i]) == Convert.ToString(listBox3.Text[i]))
        {
            listBox4.Items.Add(goldensheep[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have all the data listed in `listBox1`, `listBox2` and `listBox3`, the target is `listBox4`.
Names can be found in arrays: "goldensheep", "goldenbull", "goldenostrich" but I have only used "goldensheep" here since I believe(d) that is the only one, needed here.

When I click button1, I get an error, but unfortunately I have no idea why this occurs.

**Thanks in advance, have a nice day! :)**

Comment: Please tell us what the exact error is, you are seeing.

Comment: "The index pointed outside the boundaries of the array" - or something like that, my VS is not English.

Comment: Can you explain your intensions of your usage of `Convert.ToString()`?

Comment: Not really. I thought I had to convert them in order to be able to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this would do the trick. I haven't compiled them so beware of syntax errors. I have used a hashset because it automatically ignores previously existing items, so they won't be repeated in listbox4.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HashSet<string> Suspects = new HashSet<string>();

    for(int i=0; i< listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string L1Name = (string)Listbox1.Items[i];
      
        for (int j=0; j< listBox2.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            if ((string)Listbox2.Items[j] == L1Name)
                Suspects.Add(L1Name);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < listBox3.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            if ((string)Listbox3.Items[j] == L1Name)
                Suspects.Add(L1Name);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string L2Name = (string)listBox2.Items[i];              

        for (int j = 0; j < listBox3.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            if ((string)Listbox3.Items[j] == L2Name)
                Suspects.Add(L2Name);
        }
    }

    listBox4.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string susp in Suspects)
        listBox4.Items.Add(susp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You receive the error because the last index of `listBox1` or `listBox3` is smaller than n2.  You actually are comparing only the Items of the same index for each list.

I would `addRange()` all three lists, `distinct()` them to receive all possible names. Loop through those names to check if they appear in all three lists.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it. I am kind of new to programming, even newer in form app programming.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
var lv2Items = from ListViewItem item in listView2.Items
          select item.Text;

var lv3Items = from ListViewItem item in listView3.Items
          select item.Text;

var commonNames = from ListViewItem item in listView1.Items
            where lv2Items.Contains(item.Text)
            where lv3Items.Contains(item.Text)
            select item;

foreach(var item in commonNames)
{
    ListViewItem commonName = new ListViewItem();
    commonName.Text = item.Text;

    for (int i = 0; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
    {
        commonName.SubItems.Add(item.SubItems[i].Text);
    }
    listView4.Items.Add(commonName);
}
```

`lv2Items` and `lv3Items` pulls the `Text` property of each item in `listView2` and `listView3`. `commonNames` then selects items from `listView1` where the `Text` property of that item appears in `listView2` or `listView3`. The `foreach` at the end places all elements from `commonNames` into `listView4`.

This should work regardless of the size of each of the lists, and will work regardless of what order the elements are stored in. It will only work if the string values for the `Text` property are exact matches, which is something to consider if these are actual guest lists and not hypothetical.